# Determine if today is Monday

Tags: excel, vba

How would I code an IF statement if I was trying to say

```
IF the date today is equal to Monday THEN

    Have Outlook prepare 3 emails

ELSE 

    Have Outlook prepare 2 emails

END IF
```

I just need the "IF the date today is equal to Monday."

Comment: I would think about increasing your Acception rate in order for people to answer your future questions.

Comment: Click the empty Tick under the number of votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
If Weekday(Now()) = vbMonday Then
    MsgBox "Monday"
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using an IF statement, I would use a SELECT CASE statement instead:

```
Select Case Weekday(Now())    
    Case vbMonday    
      'Create 3 emails

    Case vbTuesday    
      'Create 2 emails

    Case Else       
      'Do something else

End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

VBA offers you a variety of date functions. You would need the [`Date`](http://office2010.microsoft.com/client/helppreview14.aspx?AssetId=HV080007531&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL.DEV&Version=14&tl=2&pid=CH080007519&CTT=4) function to get the actual date, and the [`Weekday`](http://office2010.microsoft.com/client/helppreview14.aspx?AssetId=HV080007642&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL.DEV&Version=14&tl=2&queryid=&respos=1) function to get the weekday from a given date.

You condition would have to look like

```
If Weekday(Date) = vbMonday then
    ' create email
Else
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
if (Weekday(Date, vbSunday) = vbMonday) then
   ...
else
   ...
end if
```